# If i try to change width & height of an image the image size increases.What should i do in order to get a reduced size image?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, resize

Change width & height of an image with reduced size

```
Image Resize(Image image, int w, int h)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h);
        Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphic.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphic.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphic.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);

        graphic.Dispose();
        return bmp; 
    }
```

Even if i'm reducing the width & height of an image my image size increases.How to fix this ?

I expect the converted file to be of less size than the original image.

Comment: What format is source image?

Comment: `my image size increases.` What do you mean by this? Do you mean you saved it to disk? Or something else? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: What is your original image format and its size? Also, let me know your saving image format.

Comment: image format is jpg with 270kb size but after conversion it becomes double the size.

Comment: Add the code you use to save it. You're probably saving it as png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if u want to reduce storage of image, this can be what u want:

```
// Make sure to include this at the top
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

/// <summary> 
/// Saves an image as a jpeg image, with the given quality 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="path"> Path to which the image would be saved. </param> 
/// <param name="quality"> An integer from 0 to 100, with 100 being the highest quality. </param> 
public static void SaveJpeg (string path, Image img, int quality) 
{ 
    if (quality<0  ||  quality>100) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("quality must be between 0 and 100."); 

     // Encoder parameter for image quality 
     EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality); 
     // JPEG image codec 
     ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg"); 
     EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1); 
     encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam; 
     img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams); 
} 

/// <summary> 
/// Returns the image codec with the given mime type 
/// </summary> 
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType) 
{ 
     // Get image codecs for all image formats 
     ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders(); 

     // Find the correct image codec 
     for(int i=0; i<codecs.Length; i++) 
         if(codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType) 
             return codecs[i]; 

     return null; 
 }
```

Then you can do this:

```
// First load the image somehow
Image myImage = Image.FromFile(pathToImage, true); 
// Save the image with a quality of 50% 
SaveJpeg (destImagePath, myImage, 50);
```